# Using "doas" with root password instead of user password

Tags: privileges, doas

From my limited understanding, the `doas` utility allows you to run any command as root but, by default, requires you to enter your own password instead of the root user's password.

How do I make it require root password instead?

Comment: You don't.  Shared passwords - as you are describing - are bad for a lot of reasons.

Comment: Out of curiosity can you list some of those reasons?

Comment: @NickKeeger The fact that `su` can be used with the root password to gain root access without even using `sudo` or `doas` is a big reason. This means that no manner of configuring `sudo` or `doas` would disallow a user with the root password from gaining root access.  Also, changing the root password could be done by anyone with access to it, instantly cutting off access from everyone else.

Comment: @NickKeeger 
- With root passwords it's harder to keep track in the logs who did what as root
- Often you also don't want users to run everything on the system as root but only certain commands (this also holds for a single user system, most daemons have their own username)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to achieve with `doas`, by design. If you need to run a command as root using the root password, you may do so on a Linux system using the `su` command like so:

```
su - -c "command"
```

(single dash is used to get the root environment when switching)

On a BSD system, you would instead use

```
su root -c "command"
```

(Note that the `-c` option is passed to the root user's shell. It is not an option to `su` in this case.)

Comment: The question was about `doas`. Also, as mentioned in the comments in the question: A system should not have a root password

Comment: @Garo "should not have a root password" is irrelevant as the question presumes that there is a root password. Note that I also have edited the given answer to address why using `su` in this case is the better approach.